Minimizer $C^* = \textrm{argmin}_{C} \sum_i \lVert P P^+ A_i C^+ C - A_i \rVert_F^2$
Given $P \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$ and $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times D}$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$ with $D > M$, I am looking to find the minimizer $C^* \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times D}$ of
$$C^* = \textrm{argmin}_{C} \sum_{i=0}^k \lVert P P^+ A_i C^+ C - A_i \rVert_F^2$$
I realize that an analytical solution is unlikely, given that the derivative of the energy with respect to $C$ is nonlinear. Otherwise, I would be happy with an iterative procedure to estimate $C$. The problem also is similar to Gradient of $\lVert \mathbf{H}^{\dagger}\mathbf{H} - \mathbf{B}\rVert_F^2$.
The problem arises from considering the minimization problem
$$ C^*, \{T^*_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq k} = \textrm{argmin}_{C, \{T_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq k}} \sum_{i=0}^k \lVert P T_i C - A_i \rVert^2_F$$
where $T_i \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$. Initially, my thought to solve this was to start with some initial guess of $C$, solve for $\{T_i\}$ with $C$ fixed, then fix $\{T_i\}$ and solve for $C$, iterating until convergence.  However, given that for fixed $C$, the minimal solution is $T_i^* = P^+ A_i C^+$ I reckoned (perhaps wrongly) that this second problem could be converted to the first by replacing $T_i$ with the optimal solution given $C$.
Really, my end goal is to solve the latter problem quickly and efficiently, and I'm curious if reformulating it into a minimization problem over $C$ could make things easier.
Edit: Using the fact that $P^+P$ and $C^+C$ are symmetric and idempotent, the problem reduces to finding the minimizer
$$C^* = \textrm{argmin}_{C} \sum_{i=0}^k \mathrm{tr}( A_i^T (P^+P - I) C^+ C) + \mathrm{tr}(A_i^T A_i (I - C^+ C) )$$
Edit 2: Following the derivation in the previous question linked above the gradient of the first functional w.r.t. to $C$,
$$f(C) = \sum_{i=0}^k \lVert P P^+ A_i C^+ C - A_i \rVert_F^2$$
(remarkably) reduces to the simple form
$$ \frac{d f}{d C} = - (C^+)^T \left[ \sum_{i=0}^k A_i^T P P^+ A_i \right] (I - C^+ C).$$
Since $C = 0$ gives $\frac{d f}{d C} = 0$, a reasonable additional regularizer in the context of this problem would be adding the term $\lVert P C - B\rVert^2$ to get
$$ \tilde{f}(C) = f(C) + \lVert P C - B\rVert^2,$$
whose gradient w.r.t. to $C$ is now
$$\frac{d\tilde{f}}{dC} = - (C^+)^T \left[ \sum_{i=0}^k A_i^T P P^+ A_i \right] (I - C^+ C) + 2 P^T P C - 2 P^T B,$$
which does not vanish when $C = 0$. In this form, is there a clever way to solve for $C$? Otherwise, it appears that a nonlinear solver is potentially the best answer, though which one is optimal for the problem is the important question.

Are you looking for argmin or min? According to your text, you might want to write argmin.

argmin, thanks! Edited to fix.
